# vb.net Open File - Chrome & IE

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I've been having a nightmare getting a method to open a file working, until I tested the process in Chrome and discovered it worked so it can only be an issue within IE. Unfortunately some of the users will surely be using IE so I still need to resolve the issue. Here's what I've got:

```
   Protected Sub OpenFile(filePath As String) 

    If dlCvFlName Is Nothing Or dlCvFlPath Is Nothing Then
        lblError.Text = 'The Candidate does not have a CV uploaded'
    Else
        Dim script As String = "window.open('" & filePath & "', 'Popup', '_newtab');"
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "open", script, True)
    End If
End Sub

OpenFile("www.domain.com/file/document.doc")
```

When I run this in chrome the file is successfully opened, however absolutely nothing happens in IE...

Please help...?

Comment: Have you tried adding http:// to the filePath?

Comment: Yes, I have that on the actual code, I just forgot to put it on here... It works fine in chrome though, it's really bugging me now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive the issue is your `_newtab` name - this isn't typically supported.

Options should be:

_blank - URL is loaded into a new window. This is default

_parent - URL is loaded into the parent frame

_self - URL replaces the current page

_top - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded

Remove `_newtab` and try again..

**Also**

Because the user isn't actually actioning this themselves - I.E you are injecting javascript to force a popup on page_load - the browsers popup blocker will surely intercept it.

You would be better off attaching the `window.open` method to a button and have javascript fire on the page, rather than posting back and injecting it.

Comment: I tried that, I thought it might work, but still having the same problem. When I click the button to run the event the cursor briefly has a funny little exclamation mark appear but no message... Grrrr...

Comment: Right, it's the popup blocker in IE, any suggestions on how I can get round this..?

Comment: The only thing you can do is execute your window.open without doing the postback part. I.E have your code on the page ready to fire. Then a button to fire that code. This way the user is actioning the popup and it's not firing on a page load. this will be the best chance.. popup blockers are a pain for things like this.

Comment: Ah, the button is in an update panel, so if I move it outside of that I might be cool, I'll try it first thing tomorrow. Thanks for your help, I'll let you know how I get on...